# How do I create a dictionary from a Pandas dataframe with a specific format

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

| To | From | Place | From_to_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0xA | 0xB | 1024 | 0xA to 0xB |
| 0xA | 0xC | 1026 | 0xA to 0xC |
| 0xB | 0xC | 1025 | 0xB to 0xC |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0xZZ | 0xA | 1623 | 0xZZ to 0xA |

My desired dictionary output should look like this:

'''

```
{'data': {'id':'0xA', 'label':'0xA'},
'position': {'x':1024, 'y':1024}},
'data': {'id':'0xB', 'label':'0xB'},
'position': {'x':1025, 'y':1025}},
{'data': {'id':'0xC', 'label':'0xC'},
'position': {'x':1026, 'y':1026}},
...
{'data': {'id':'0xZZ', 'label':'0xZZ'},
'position': {'x':1623, 'y':1623}},

{'data':{'source':'0xA', 'target':'0xB', 'label': '0xA to 0xB'}},
{'data':{'source':'0xA', 'target':'0xC', 'label': '0xA to 0xC'}},
{'data':{'source':'0xB', 'target':'0xC', 'label': '0xB to 0xC'}},
...
{'data':{'source':'0xZZ', 'target':'0xA', 'label': '0xZZ to 0xA'}},
```

'''

Comment: In ouput is not swapped `source` and `target`? Because in sample `target` is created from `From`, correct should be `To`

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake typing that out - you're correct source is From and Target is To

Answer (score 0):

First part is generated by `To` and `From` columns with `Place` with remove duplicates, by default keep first value, then convert to dictionary, add keys with `zip` for `L12` list and for `L3` only rename columns with add key `data` and last join both lists:

```
df1 = (df.melt(id_vars='Place', value_vars=['To','From'])
         .drop_duplicates('value')
         .sort_values('Place'))

L1 = df1[['value','value']].set_axis(['id','label'], axis=1).to_dict('records')
print (L1)

L2 = df1[['Place','Place']].set_axis(['x','y'], axis=1).to_dict('records')
print (L2)

L3 = df[['From','To','From_to_To']].rename(columns={'From':'source','To':'target','From_to_To':'label'}).to_dict('records')
L3 = [{'data':a} for a in L3]
print (L3)


L12 = [{'data':a, 'position':b} for a, b in zip(L1, L2)]
print (L12)

L = L12 + L3
print (L)
[{'data': {'id': '0xA', 'label': '0xA'}, 'position': {'x': 1024, 'y': 1024}},
 {'data': {'id': '0xB', 'label': '0xB'}, 'position': {'x': 1025, 'y': 1025}},
 {'data': {'id': '0xC', 'label': '0xC'}, 'position': {'x': 1026, 'y': 1026}}, 
 {'data': {'id': '0xZZ', 'label': '0xZZ'}, 'position': {'x': 1623, 'y': 1623}},
 {'data': {'source': '0xB', 'target': '0xA', 'label': '0xA to 0xB'}}, 
 {'data': {'source': '0xC', 'target': '0xA', 'label': '0xA to 0xC'}}, 
 {'data': {'source': '0xC', 'target': '0xB', 'label': '0xB to 0xC'}}, 
 {'data': {'source': '0xA', 'target': '0xZZ', 'label': '0xZZ to 0xA'}}]
```

Comment: Thanks this was amazing!! I realized I made a fatal error... my output should be one big dictionary instead of an array. :( Anyway we can solve this? :D
Maybe, I should of started from the very top - I start with a JSON file, and I placed it into a dataframe thinking it would be easier to manipulate, but perhaps I should got straight from JSON into this nested dictionary final output?? @jezrael - any suggestions? - thank you again so much